# I am not able to find build error in visual studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

There are some build error which I am not getting.
First It asked to put scanf_s instead of scanf and then again build error

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    void main()
    {
    float d,u,a,t;
    printf("\nEnter the accelaration(m/sec sq):  ");
    scanf_s("%f",&a);
    printf("Enter the time(s): ");
    scanf_s("%f",&t);
    printf("Enter the initial velocity:  ");
    scanf_s("%f",&u);
    d=a*t+(u*t*t)/2;
    printf("The distance covered is %f mtrs  ",d);



}




/* 1>------ Build started: Project: small progarm, Configuration: Debug   Win32 ------
1>Build started 14-Jul-15 12:01:32 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\small progarm.unsuccessfulbuild".  
1>ClCompile:
1>  small practice programs.cpp
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1123: failure during conversion to COFF: file   invalid or corrupt
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.49
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
*/
```

Comment: and....what is the error?

Comment: Try a filename without spaces.

Comment: By the way, `d = u * t + 0.5 * a * t * t`. Test carefully before burning onto you satellite guidance system chip!

Comment: Start a new project from scratch with a minimal `void main(){}` program and try if that one compiles. If not, there may be a problem with your VS2010 installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this, from Microsoft -

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2757355

It states -

**Cause:** The issue is caused by a dependency failure of cvtres.exe on msvcr100_clr0400.dll which is shipped with Visual Studio 2010 RTM and eventually updated with a new version when Visual Studio 2012 RTM or .NET Framework 4.5 is installed.

**Resolution:** To resolve this link error, upgrade Visual Studio 2010 RTM to VS 2010 SP1. Upgrading to VS 2010 SP1 resolves the dependency failure and the VC++ 2010 project builds with no LNK1123 error.